# Is this a design fault or I shall learn how to use SD cards with PI?

Tags: sd-card, safety, design

My Respberry Pi Mod B arrived last week and I spent the whole weekend to try out different OSes, softwares etc. For this purpose I have to plug in and out the SD card again and again.

Last night I suddenly found my SDHC card does not work on my card reader of PC. Further investigation shows the SDHC card seems to be damaged on the inner corner (the other side of the "missing corner"). Of cause, it does not work on the Pi as well. In addition to that, a little piece of the SD card can still been found in the Pi's SD card slot.

So I brought another SDHC card for the Pi, cleaned up the Pi's SD card slot, wrote the OS image to the SDHC card. However, the Pi didn't start!

I think have to return my Pi. However, what I want to ask here is, as I didn't remember how I made the damage to the card and the Pi, is this a weakness by design? Did anybody have been in the same situation before? How can I avoid further damage?

UPDATE:

I fixed my Pi. According to investigation, 2 of the SD card slot trampolines was found to be flatten so they are not connect properly. Also, although the real reason of the damage remains unknown, but the most likely suspects are considered to be - my 4yo son and 1.5yo daughter.

Thanks for the commenters, I learn from them to observe the contacts so I can finally bring my Pi back to running!

Pictures for reference:

[image: Damaged SD Card On Left-top corner]
[image: Flattened trampolines 1]
[image]

Comment: Hopefully you haven't killed your Pi, is it possible one of the contacts is bent and not making a reliable connection?

Comment: This seems really unlikely and I doubt it will affect many people.. Would you be able to attach a picture of the SD card slot to your question so we can take a look?

Comment: Are you sure nobody stepped on it? Chipping an SD card to the point it stops working is really difficult. It could not have just broke like that from normal wear and tear. I second the motion . PHOTO PLEASE!

Comment: Hi EarthEngine. Could you post your answer below? Future readers will find it easier to separate the question and the answer that way.